# VBA macro using countif with three columns

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I have an Excel with three columns.

```
Column A:               Column B:    Column C:    
shirts (long, short)    color        age
```

Now I need to find out how many long, green shirts there are with an age of 10. Of course I now how to filter it manually but I would like to do it automatically. Actually I have a much more complex Excel file with around 80k rows and I need to find out a couple more numbers. A solution for the above given example will do the job for me though. I will just adapt it to my actual file. I have found a few possible solutions but I think a simple countIf function will be the easiest or will it not be performant enough when it comes to over 80k rows? I also struggle to build a countIf function that uses two additional columns. I started to do it like this. Count the long shirts if the value of B is "green" and the value of column C is "10". Basically I would like to know if this is a proper solution and how the function could look like.

Comment: add the code you have tried with the question. Instead of explaining the formula, add the formula you used

Comment: My attempt was so poor I thought it was better not to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 3 conditions to your `Count` you need to use `CountIfs` function (and not `CountIf`).

The code below will do the job for the 3 columns you've provided, and the example in your post:

```
Dim CountIfsRes As Long

CountIfsRes = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "=long", Range("B:B"), "=green", Range("C:C"), "=10")

MsgBox CountIfsRes
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works if you want to know how many long green shirts there are.

In the event you have multiple conditions you want to populate in a summary table you can adapt this formula to do so and insert the formula into a table.

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"long",B:B,"green",C:C,"10")`